# CodeIgniter Dropdown menu fetching data from database column

Tags: database, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, sqlyog

I am having a problem. Please let me know if there is a solution. I am new to codeigniter therefore, sorry in advance if there is a silly one!

I am trying to fetch data from a database. Table name is `fw_main_cat` which have fields (`cat_id`, `cat_parent_id`, `cat_level`, `cat_title`, `cat_menu_order` and `cat_status`). `cat_id` is unique.

I want a dropdown menu (in view) to take all the data of a column `cat_title` through `cat_level` (which are int). So, how can I do?

Here is my code which I have tried so far.

**This is Model :**

```
public function cat_level_one($cat_level) 
{

   $sql = "Select * from fw_main_cat Where cat_level=? ";
   $result =  $this->db->query($sql, $cat_level);

   if($result->num_rows() > 0)
   {
    return $result->result_array();
   }
   else { return false;
   }
}
```

**This is Controller :**

```
public function getcategory() 
{

    if ($this->session->userdata('session_status'))
    {
        $cat_level_one = $this->admin_cat_model->cat_level_one($cat_level);
        $data['cat_level_one'] = $this->admin_cat_model->cat_level_one($cat_level);
        $this->session->set_userdata('cat_level', $_POST['cat_level']);

        $this->laod_view('admin_view/admin_cat/view_add_category', $data);
    }else {
        redirect ('admin_view/admin_cat/view_category');
    }
}
```

**This is View (dropdown menu):**

```
<li class="full-row">
    <select name = 'cat_level_one' id = 'cat_level_one'>

      <option value="<?php if(isset ($cat_level_one) && $cat_level_one != ''){ foreach ($cat_level_one as $cat_one){ echo $cat_one->cat_id; } }  ?>" 
    selected="selected">------------Select Category------------</option>
```

Thanks! for the consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code -

```
// in model

function cat_level_one($cat_level)
{
$this->db->where('cat_level',$cat_level);
$q = $this->db->get('fw_main_cat');
$data = $q->result_array();
return $data;
}


//controller function

public function getcategory()
{

**if ($this->session->userdata('session_status'))
{
$data['cat_level_one'] = $this->admin_cat_model->cat_level_one($cat_level);**

//Where this post data comes from??
$this->session->set_userdata('cat_level', $_POST['cat_level']);

$this->laod_view('admin_view/admin_cat/view_add_category', $data);
}else {
redirect ('admin_view/admin_cat/view_category');
}
}


//in view

<li class="full-row">
    <select name = 'cat_level_one' id = 'cat_level_one'>
        <option value="">-- Select Category --</option>
        <?php foreach($cat_level_one as $cat_one){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cat_one->cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat_one->cat_title; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</li>
```

Comment: sir i have tried your updated code. but its not working for me :(. still its showing blank drop-down. not fetching values from database

Comment: Do you have records in table 'fw_main_cat' for $cat_level value, you are passing?

Comment: Yes sir it contains int values

Comment: CREATE TABLE `fw_main_cat` (
  `cat_id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_parent_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `cat_level` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `cat_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cat_menu_order` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `cat_status` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: You should check your controller function if session is working or not, also you haven't passed the value of $cat_level.